# How do you transfer a programs database to another device

Tags: 2.1-eclair, data-recovery

I am using the **Book Catalog** program to scan and enter my collection of books.

This program provides an export/backup and import feature, so I can transfer the entered data onto another device.

But I am wondering now: programs can create databases on one device. **Can you transfer these database onto another device ?**

More specific, could I buy another Samsung Galaxy (or any other Android powered device) and transfer the database onto it for use with the same program (without the export/import feature ) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This only applies if you have root access, as Bryan already pointed out in the comments.*

I would suggest using a utility such as [TitaniumBackup](http://matrixrewriter.com/android/) to completely back-up all your applications **and** your data. It will be stored on your SD card so that you can transfer its files to another device and restore the backups on there.

Comment: Note that TitaniumBackup requires root (to backup application data).

Comment: @Bryan You're right, I tend to forget my phone is rooted.

Comment: @Bryan Denny: I don't know what rooted means or how to do it, although I have a very good idea of it and I'm sure this site will have some answers on how to root your phone. I am a developer, but since I'm learning Android (and it's development just now), I'm a little hesitant to give myself to many priviliges just yet. I know what one can do to a device if you do not have the knowledge to do ik correct.